# generic type of class property

Tags: c#, wpf, generics

I have the following classes:

**BaseField:**

```
public abstract class BaseField {
    ...
    public BaseField()
    {

    }

    public BaseField(E_FieldType fieldType)
    {
        _FieldType = fieldType;
    }
}
```

**TextField:**

```
public class TextField : BaseField {
    ...
    public TextField() : base(E_FieldType.Text)
    {

    }
}
```

**DateField:**

```
public class DateField : BaseField {
    ...
    public DateField() : base(E_FieldType.Date)
    {

    }
}
```

And **DataBlock** class which should contain **TextField** or **DateField**:

```
public class DataBlock<T> : BaseBlock where T : BaseField, new() {
    ...
    private T _Field;
    public DataBlock(string name): base(name, E_BlockType.Data) 
    {
        _Field = new T();            
    }
}
```

The following line works fine:

```
DataBlock<TextField> db = new DataBlock<TextField>("qwe");
```

But It is not possible to write this code:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataBlock<BaseField>> DataBlockList { get; set; }

public DataBlockViewModel()
{
    DataBlockList = new ObservableCollection<DataBlock<BaseField>>();
    DataBlockList.Add(new DataBlock<TextField>("qwe"));
    DataBlockList.Add(new DataBlock<DateField>("asd"));
}
```

The error is:

> 'BaseField' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
>   method `'DataBlock<T>'`

Could you please advise how to solve the issue that I  can create `ObservableCollection<DataBlock<BaseField>>` collection?

I can remove `new()` from `public class DataBlock<T> : BaseBlock where T : BaseField` and

```
public DataBlock(string name): base(name, E_BlockType.Data) 
{
    //_Field = new T();            
}
```

In this case I can create `DataBlockList = new ObservableCollection<DataBlock<BaseField>>();`

but it is not possible to write:

```
DataBlockList.Add(new DataBlock<TextField>("qwe"));
DataBlockList.Add(new DataBlock<DateField>("asd"));
```

Comment: Consider clarifying why making `BaseField` "non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor" is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get rid of the error:

1) You can make the class `BaseField` non-abstract

```
public abstract class BaseField {
    ...
    public BaseField()
    {

    }

    public BaseField(E_FieldType fieldType)
    {
        _FieldType = fieldType;
    }
}
```

2) Pass the new `BaseField` object as constructor parameter to `DataBlock` and remove the `new()` constraint.

```
public class DataBlock<T> : BaseBlock where T : BaseField {
    ...
    private T _Field;
    public DataBlock(string name, T field): base(name, E_BlockType.Data) 
    {
        _Field = field;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think, the second way suits me :)